# How the resolution of an image change when it is out of focus?

Tags: optics, lenses, imaging

do you know if does exist a relationship between resolution and out of focus imaging?

For example given a lens, an aperture and a distance d. How can I calculate how much out of focus is an object when it is at distance d from the lens?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the text "Modern Optical Engineering", by Warren J. Smith (McGraw-Hill). The 2nd edition has Figures 11.16 and 11.17 which show normalized curves showing the effect of defocus on MTF curves. MTF stands for Modulation Transfer Function, which is commonly used as a measure of resolution (not the only measure).  (I'm pretty sure the curves are in all editions).  The curves are normalized to the maximum spatial frequency for a lens, which is given by 1/(lambda*f#), where lambda is the wavelength and f# is the f# of the imaging bundle.  If you know the maximum spatial frequency of your lens system, you can read the curves for the spatial frequency that you care about most.

Be careful: Smith explains that one of the figures is better if the aberrations (i.e. defocus) are small, and one is only accurate for larger amounts of defocus.

For defocus problems, people usually think about defocus as the distance of the image plane from the ideal image plane location, not the distance from the lens itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about how the resolution changes as the plane of observation moves out of the focal plane of a lens, is to consider a Gaussian beam. It will have its smallest size $w_0$ in the focal plane. The size of the Gaussian beam changes with distance from the focal distance by the following relation
$$ w(z) = w_0 \sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{z_R^2}} , $$
where $z_R$ is the Rayleigh range given by
$$ z_R = \frac{\pi w_0^2}{\lambda} , $$
with $\lambda$ being the wavelength.

If the Gaussian beam is produced by a lens that is focussing another Gaussian beam which has a width $w_{in}$ in the front focal plane of the lens. Then $w_{in}$ and $w_0$ are related by
$$ w_0 = \frac{\lambda f}{\pi w_{in}} . $$
(You can think of $w_{in}$ as the radius of an aperture.)

The more general case where you do not have Gaussian beams may differs slightly from these relationships in that there may be slightly different numerical factors (of order 1), but the behavior of the scale parameters (those with dimensions of distance) would be the same.